# I'm a respectable predator (?, 7, 9, 7)

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, story

My head hurts... I feel like I'm missing something. "Avoid notes" starts with the left heading, reportedly. Ends firsts, like extremely terrifyingly impressively clearly plainly solved:
`One Refined Gander (G, 7, 7, 5) - Greatly Genteel Goose`

```
One Nasty Sucker (A, 10, 5, 8)
One Terrible Penguin (B, 9, 3, 4)
One Spooky Spider (C, 9, 6, 6)
One Evil Waterfowl (D, 10, 9, 4)
One Active Horse (E, 9, 9, 6)
One Illegal Amphibian (F, 10, 9, 4)
One Talkative Ruminant (G, 9, 9, 4)
One Heart-rending Jumper (H, 11, 5-8, 4)
One Large Lemur (I, 12, 7, 5)
One Hawkish Stinger (J, 9, 10, 9)
One Lively Marsupial (K, 6, 7, 8)
One Disabled Spitter (L, 10, 4, 5)
One Wicked Deer (M, 7, 10, 5)
One Kind Singer (N, 10, 4, 11)
One Angry Ape (O, 9, 8, 9)
One Important Antarctician (P, 8, 9, 7)
One Silent Pheasant (Q, 11, 5, 5)
One Uncommon African (R, 6, 4, 10)
One Foolish Slitherer (S, 10, 5, 5)
One Pondering Snapper (T, 5, 8, 6)
One Sympathetic Sheep (U, 10, 13, 5)
One Fat Scavenger (V, 7, 10, 7)
One Clever Tusker (W, 6, 5, 6)
```

I seem to be in a dungeon? I found this note, clutched in the hand of a skeleton:

```
Oh, Lament for I
weep tears of insanity
the immortalized drudgery
and yet my needed death
Always to be vexingly absent
Oh, Lament for I
weep tears of insanity
the endless emotions
the years are gone and nothing remains...
Oh, I weep for Something -
'tis myself! Abolish me!
Finally taken all the way to
a purgatory of unfathomable horror -
there, the great torture of losing
my soul: after it, I never aged;
Nor could harm oneself
Oh, Lament! Bountiful terror of Immortality
Oh, Lament! Unusual horror of an Eternal Life
```

Lest I forget, they left some ravings on the wall, mayhaps like this:

```
Oh, why to offend Nyx!
9 45 ' 21 6 2 38 22 53 10 51 13 44 12 40 17 39 1 48 3 55  
22 34 21 53 4 40 11 37 15 49 18 39 8 61 19 51 16 62  
22 42 6 40 18 8 16 45 2 8 3 16 5 36 14 40 7 55 7 61 9 32  
13 34 7 15 23 51 20 55 3 53 12 55 17 42 17 50 1 7 1 36  
21 4 2 10 10 58 14 13 3 5 4 4 4 49 9 8 8 23 23 1 1 54 4 7 4 53 23 44  
Never again can I do so
```

Aiii, I can't remember: who am I, and what do I want?

**Edit/Hint:**
Seeing as there are *so* many ways to say the same thing (apparently some are valid, even *with* the enigmatic constraints), I will be revealing the the individual intended answers below, once a valid solution is posted:

> ```
>  One Nasty Sucker (A, 10, 5, 8) - Absolutely Awful Anteater
>  One Terrible Penguin (B, 9, 3, 4) - Blatantly Bad Bird
>  One Spooky Spider (C, 9, 6, 6) - Certainly Creepy Crawly
>  One Evil Waterfowl (D, 10, 9, 4) - Distinctly Dastardly Duck
>  One Active Horse (E, 9, 9, 6) - Evidently Energetic Equine
>  One Illegal Amphibian (F, 10, 9, 4) - Flagrantly Felonious Frog
>  One Talkative Ruminant (G, 9, 9, 4) - Glaringly Garrulous Goat
>  One Heart-rending Jumper (H, 11, 5-8, 4) - Harrowingly Heart-breaking Hare
>  One Large Lemur (I, 12, 7, 5) - Impressively Immense Indri
>  One Hawkish Stinger (J, 9, 10, 9) - Juttingly Jingoistic Jellyfish
>  One Lively Marsupial (K, 6, 7, 8) - Keenly Kicking Kangaroo
>  One Disabled Spitter (L, 10, 4, 5) - Luminously Lame Llama
>  One Wicked Deer (M, 7, 10, 5) - Majorly Malevolent Moose
>  One Kind Singer (N, 10, 4, 11) - Noticeably Nice Nightingale
>  One Angry Ape (O, 9, 8, 9) - Obviously Outraged Orangutan
>  One Important Antarctician (P, 8, 9, 7) - Palpably Prominent Penguin
>  One Silent Pheasant (Q, 11, 5, 5) Quotidianly Quiet Quail
>  One Uncommon African (R, 6, 4, 10) - Really Rare Rhinoceros
>  One Foolish Slitherer (S, 10, 5, 5) - Strikingly Silly Snake
>  One Pondering Snapper (T, 5, 8, 6) - Truly Thinking Turtle
>  One Sympathetic Sheep (U, 10, 13, 5) - Undeniably Understanding Urial 
>  One Fat Scavenger (V, 7, 10, 7) - Visibly Voluminous Vulture
>  One Clever Tusker (W, 6, 5, 6) - Wildly Witty Walrus
> ```

---

**Hint:**

> My mother always told me to examine prey from top to bottom before consumption

---

**Hint:**

> "A void notes starts with the title". Make what you will of it.

---

**Hint:**

> Never offend N(y,x)

---

**Hint:**

> Perhaps you're up for a fantastic game of Charates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some attempts at solving the first part. Don't know how useful this is for the entire riddle...

> One Terrible Penguin (B, 9, 3, 4) - ?? BAD BIRD
>  One Spooky Spider (C, 9, 6, 6) - ?? CREEPY ??
>  One Evil Waterfowl (D, 10, 9, 4) - ?? DASTARDLY Duck
>   One Heart-rending Jumper (H, 11, 5-8 4) - ?? HEART-BREAKING HARE
>  One Hawkish Stinger (J, 9, 10, 9) - ?? JINGOISTIC JELLYFISH
>  One Lively Marsupial (K, 6, 7, 8) - ?? KICKING KANGAROO
>  One Disabled Spitter (L, 10, 4, 5) - !Legitimate Lame LLAMA
>  One Wicked Deer (M, 7, 10, 5) - ?? ??  Moose
>  One Kind Singer (N, 10, 4, 11) - ?? NICE NIGHTINGALE
>  One Silent Pheasant (Q, 11, 5, 5) - ?? QUIET QUAIL
>  One Sympathetic Sheep (U, 10, 13, 5) - ! ?? UNDERSTANDING URIAL

EDIT: Removed all fully solved clues, which are now found in the original post; ! signifies one of the words is wrong, and ALL CAPS is confirmed correct.

Comment: Partially right: B, C, F, J, K, N, Q, W
 Partially right, partially wrong: A, D, E, G, I, L, M, P, U
 Completely wrong: Formatting, 
 Completely right: O - get rid of the "-", R, S, T, V

Comment: Couple more stabs at some:
 A 10 = rot13(Nofbyhgryl)  , 
B 3 = rot13(Onq)

Comment: H 4 = rot13(Uner)

Comment: N 11 is probably rot13(avtugvatnyr)

Comment: N11 correct, H4 correct, A10 correct but A8 still wrong (current suggestion is the wrong length), B3 correct. Nice job :)

Comment: E5 = rot13(rdhvq). K7 could be rot13(xvpxvat). N11 = rot13(avtugvatnyr). U5 looks like it should be rot13(hivar), but that's not a word; the real word for that concept is rot13(bivar).

Comment: A8 could be rot13(nneqinex); if not that, then rot13(nagrngre).

Comment: E5 correct, except I can't count (it's actually E6) - this will be remedied. As the whole answer has been constructed, I will post it. K7 correct, N11 already verified, U5 wrong, A8 correct, but current A10 doesn't fit the enigmatic criteria.

Comment: Fix: current A10, *does* fit the enigmatic criteria, full phrase shortly posted.

Comment: Q11 = rot13(dhvrfpragyl)? W6 = rot13(jvyqyl)? Another stab at U5: rot13(hevny)

Comment: F9 = rot (Srybavbhf)

Comment: possibility U5 = rot13(hevny)

Comment: possibility I5 = rot13 (vaqev)

Comment: Updated based on comments.

Comment: H5-8: rot13(Urneg-oernxvat), D9: rot13(qnfgneqyl)

Comment: F10: rot13(svraqvfuyl)

Comment: Q11 wrong, W6 correct (all correct), U5/U13 correct (U10 still wrong), I5 correct (I12 acceptable, I7 correct, so will be posted), H5-8 correct, D9 correct, F10 acceptable, F9 correct (will be posted)

Comment: U10: rot13(haqravnoyl)

Comment: D4, D9 correct, U10 correct (all correct), C is a little bit more punny (and less straightforward) than the others, so I'm posting it as well, M5 correct, L5 correct

Comment: D10: rot13(Qrpvfviryl)

Comment: M10: rot13(Znyribyrag)

Comment: M10, M5 correct, D10 acceptable (posted) (rot13(Qrsvavgryl) would have been acceptable as well)

Comment: Accepting Q11 because apparently the intended solution isn't a word :(

Comment: For the missing start of B:  rot13(Obzonfgvp Onq Oveq)?

Comment: @Mohirl Unfortunately, that doesn't fit the enigmatic constraints

Answer (score 3):

Filling in the blanks for the first section (hopefully)

> B: Brutishly Bad Blue
>  H: Hazardously Harried Hare
>  J: Jarringly Jackbooted Jellyfish
>  K: Keenly Kicking Kangaroo
>  L: Lopsidedly Lame Llama
>  M: Majorly Malevolent Moose
>  N: Noticeably Nice Nightingale

**Edit:** New suggestions

> B: Banefully Bad Bird
>  B: Balefully Bad Bird
>  L: Lamentedly Lame Llama
>  L: Laughingly Lame Llama

Comment: B9 wrong, B3 correct, B4 wrong (rot13(Vg'f nyernql pbasvezrq gb or "oveq")), H11 acceptable (will be posted), J9 acceptable (will be posted), K6 correct (all correct), L10 wrong, L4 correct, L5 correct, M7 correct (all correct), N10 correct (all correct)

Comment: With regards to the new suggestions, both L10 are incorrect, but B9 is acceptable. Considering it's the last one, I'll post L10 as well, because it's a bit of a stretch.

Answer (score 3):

As it has been 2 weeks and no progress has been posted for 1 week, I am posting the intended solution.

Firstly, it was required to parse the beginning:
*My head hurts... I feel like I'm missing something.*

> If your head hurts very badly, you could be said to have a *splitting* headache. This clues that you should split the next sentences in an odd way.

*"Avoid notes" starts with the left heading, reportedly. Ends firsts, like extremely terrifyingly impressively clearly plainly solved:*

> Noting that "ly" ends the words "extremely... plainly", the intended split is therefore "reported | Ly". Using the second part and the first example, it is possible to derive that the "ly" words are the meanings of the first words in the first section, which will all end with "ly".
>    The remaining first part is "Avoid notes" starts with the left heading, reportedly. Taking it by sound, you get "a void notes starts with the left heading". This tells you that a void (0) in the note's starts is associated with the left side of the note, and the title (a heading).

After this point, it should be possible (and it was) to solve the first section. As was found already, the answers were:

> ```
>  One Nasty Sucker (A, 10, 5, 8) - Absolutely Awful Anteater
>  One Terrible Penguin (B, 9, 3, 4) - Blatantly Bad Bird
>  One Spooky Spider (C, 9, 6, 6) - Certainly Creepy Crawly
>  One Evil Waterfowl (D, 10, 9, 4) - Distinctly Dastardly Duck
>  One Active Horse (E, 9, 9, 6) - Evidently Energetic Equine
>  One Illegal Amphibian (F, 10, 9, 4) - Flagrantly Felonious Frog
>  One Talkative Ruminant (G, 9, 9, 4) - Glaringly Garrulous Goat
>  One Heart-rending Jumper (H, 11, 5-8, 4) - Harrowingly Heart-breaking Hare
>  One Large Lemur (I, 12, 7, 5) - Impressively Immense Indri
>  One Hawkish Stinger (J, 9, 10, 9) - Juttingly Jingoistic Jellyfish
>  One Lively Marsupial (K, 6, 7, 8) - Keenly Kicking Kangaroo
>  One Disabled Spitter (L, 10, 4, 5) - Luminously Lame Llama
>  One Wicked Deer (M, 7, 10, 5) - Majorly Malevolent Moose
>  One Kind Singer (N, 10, 4, 11) - Noticeably Nice Nightingale
>  One Angry Ape (O, 9, 8, 9) - Obviously Outraged Orangutan
>  One Important Antarctician (P, 8, 9, 7) - Palpably Prominent Penguin
>  One Silent Pheasant (Q, 11, 5, 5) Quotidianly Quiet Quail
>  One Uncommon African (R, 6, 4, 10) - Really Rare Rhinoceros
>  One Foolish Slitherer (S, 10, 5, 5) - Strikingly Silly Snake
>  One Pondering Snapper (T, 5, 8, 6) - Truly Thinking Turtle
>  One Sympathetic Sheep (U, 10, 13, 5) - Undeniably Understanding Urial 
>  One Fat Scavenger (V, 7, 10, 7) - Visibly Voluminous Vulture
>  One Clever Tusker (W, 6, 5, 6) - Wildly Witty Walrus
> ```

Next, the note must be parsed:

> Going down the note, you can find:
>
> ```
>  Oh, Lament for I
>  weep tears of insanity
>  the immortalized drudgery
>  and yet my needed death
>  Always to be vexingly absent
>  Oh, Lament for I
>  weep tears of insanity
>  the endless emotions
>  the years are gone and nothing remains...
>  Oh, I weep for Something -
>  'tis myself! Abolish me!
>  Finally taken all the way to
>  a purgatory of unfathomable horror -
>  there, the great torture of losing
>  my soul: after it, I never aged;
>  Nor could harm oneself
>  Oh, Lament! Bountiful terror of Immortality
>  Oh, Lament! Unusual horror of an Eternal Life
> ```
>
> That is, **Index Into Solutions**

Now, to proceed to the third section:

> The key here is to figure out the indexing scheme. Taking the second hint, it's clear that indexing into the solutions from the first part is required. Taking the leading bit of the third part, "Oh, why to offend Nyx!", one thing stands out - "Nyx", a very unusual name. Specifically, taking off the first end ("offend") of NYX, the result (-n)YX indicates that the numbers below will be indexes of form (y, x).
>    Given that indexes are of form (y, x), the first part indicates where the indexes begin. Knowing that "a void (0) in the note's starts is associated with the left side of the note, and the title (a heading)" (previously deduced conclusion), 0 is the most obvious choice of starting index. 0 for x indices is the left side of the note, and 0 for y indices is the title (essentially making y 1-indexed for the note itself). Newline characters/OS differences are never relevant because the x-index never exceeds the length of the corresponding line.
>    Now, taking the note's number pairs and replacing them with letters, we get the following:
>
> ```
>  I'MAVIVIDLY
>  VENERABLE
>  VAMPIREBUTI
>  JUSTWANTTO
>  SLEEPETERNALLY
> ```
>
> Parsing these letters into words, we get the final form of the note itself:
>
> ```
>  Oh, why to offend Nyx!
>  I'm a Vividly
>  Venerable
>  Vampire but I
>  just want to
>  Sleep Eternally
>  Never again can I do so
> ```

Title:

> I'm a respectable predator (**V**, 7, 9, 7) - **VIVIDLY VENERABLE VAMPIRE**

Edit/Hint:

> This had the intended answers to resolve the problem of having too many options to say the same thing

Hint 1:

> This clues the way for solving the second part

Hint 2:

> This is the verbal interpretation of the first clue after splitting

Hint 3:

> This clues the idea of taking off 1 end

Hint 4:

> This clues the fact that, once you have the correct y-indices, finding x-indices is equivalent to invoking the [char-at function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_(string_functions)#CharAt), which is zero-indexed in the languages that literally invoke it as charAt() (i.e. Java, JavaScript)

Comment: I am giving the checkmark to the answer that made the most progress towards the final solution.